# Capture when laptop is suspended in AIR on OSX

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air

The high level problem is that I want to know if the user is present for a given time period in the past. This can be solved when the computer is awake by tracking `USER_IDLE` and `USER_PRESENT` events.

However, I've found that when the laptop lid is closed, it does not fire the `USER_IDLE` event, nor does it fire `USER_PRESENT` when the laptop lid is opened. The laptop can be closed for hours and neither events are ever dispatched.

So how can I know if the user is present? I've looked into all sorts of events to capture the laptop being suspended, including `SUSPEND`, `DEACTIVATE`, etc, but none do what I want.

For example, I have this test code:

```
var logFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("events.log");

var app:NativeApplication = NativeApplication.nativeApplication;
app.addEventListener(Event.USER_IDLE, logEvent);
app.addEventListener(Event.USER_PRESENT, logEvent);
app.addEventListener(Event.SUSPEND, logEvent);
app.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, logEvent);
app.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, logEvent);
app.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, logEvent);
app.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, logEvent);

logEvent(new Event("started"));

function logEvent(e:Event):void {
    var log:String = "\n" + e.type + " at " + new Date();

    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(logFile, FileMode.APPEND);
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes(log);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

If I run this app, change window focus away then back, close the laptop, then open the laptop, I get this output:

```
started at Tue Sep 1 09:29:11 GMT-0400 2015
invoke at Tue Sep 1 09:29:11 GMT-0400 2015
activate at Tue Sep 1 09:29:12 GMT-0400 2015
deactivate at Tue Sep 1 09:29:13 GMT-0400 2015
activate at Tue Sep 1 09:29:13 GMT-0400 2015
deactivate at Tue Sep 1 09:29:17 GMT-0400 2015
activate at Tue Sep 1 09:29:31 GMT-0400 2015
```

As you can see this doesn't seem to help me figure out if the user is present (laptop awake) or not. There are no `USER_IDLE` or `USER_PRESENT` events, and the `ACTIVATE` and `DEACTIVATE` events happen even when the user is present.

Is there any way to know if the laptop is suspended? Or to know if the user is present?

---

**Edit:** I guess that I can poll the system clock. A large jump in time would indicate waking up after being suspended for awhile. I'll try this.

Comment: The default time in seconds for Idle/Present is controlled via NativeApplication.idleThreshold and is 5 minutes. Now, in suspend mode, you will not receive any events of course since the laptop is suspended.. ;-)   I would believe you would need an ANE to capture the IORegisterForSystemPower based events for preparing to sleep or waking. There is the NativeApplication.timeSinceLastUserInput property that you could poll on a timer every minute or so and see if it has changed since the last poll (assuming that is where the idle/present events are calc'd)

Comment: A logical consequence of those non reported actions is that your app framerate should be changed arbitrarily, Normal framerate when computer is active and low framerate when computer is not.